# Subscriber callback function with additional arguments using ShapeShifter

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have multiple subscribers that share the same callback function. Since they subscribe to different previously unknown topics, I am using the [ShapeShifter](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/topic_tools/html/classtopic__tools_1_1ShapeShifter.html) class.

This is how one of the subscribers would be instantiated:

```
sub_ = nh.subscribe(topic, 10, &MyClass::topicCallback, this);
```

And here is my Callback:

```
void MyClass::topicCallback(const topic_tools::ShapeShifter::ConstPtr& input)
{      // do stuff    }
```

Now I'd like to pass an additional argument to that function. I found out that this is possible using boost::bind(), so the callback would look like this:

```
void MyClass::topicCallback(const topic_tools::ShapeShifter::ConstPtr& input, const std::string& arg)
{      // do stuff    }
```

and the subscriber:

```
sub_ = nh.subscribe(topic, 10, boost::bind(&MyClass::topicCb, this, _1, arg));
```

Initializing the subscriber this way doesn't work, however. [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/?answer=63998?answer=63998#post-id-63998) answer suggested to template the subscriber to the correct data type, e.g.

```
sub_ = nh.subscribe<my_data_type>(topic, 10, boost::bind(&MyClass::topicCb, this, _1, arg));
```

The point is that I don't know the message type, that's why I am using the ShapeShifter in the first place. Does anyone have an idea how I can circumvent this? Like subscribing without templating or maybe getting the message type before initializing the subscriber?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407690/subscriber-callback-function-with-additional-arguments-using-shapeshifter/) by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2022-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved, don't know why I didn't think of this earlier:

```
sub_ = nh.subscribe<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>(topic, 10, boost::bind(&MyClass::topicCallback, this, _1, topic));
```

does the job :)

---

Originally posted by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) with karma: 98 on 2022-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1